# On the definition of non elementary primitives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals

Consider $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$. It is a known fact that it does not have a primitive function that can be written from elementary functions. However, since $f$ is continuous, one can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and a primitive function can be derived, namely,
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt
$$

My question: the FTC is for compact intervals $[a,b]$, and the variable $x$ verifies $x\in [a,b]$. Can we define the primitive $F$ in all $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, you can write $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\exp\{-x^2\}dx$, being differentiable is local property of the function, so is does not matter what the lower limit is

Comment: @EgorIvanov Would you mind to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @EgorIvanov And can this be done for every continuous function?

Comment: @SineoftheTime I just changed it

Comment: No, only if that integral exists

Comment: @EgorIvanov Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a function that is continuous in the whole real line. Does it have a primitive define in the whole real line? In $\mathbb{R^+}$ is clear, since $\int_0^x f(t)dt$ verifies $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x>0$ (because of FTC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Since $f(x)$ is integrable all over $\mathbb{R}$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{a}e^{-x^2}\,dx\leq\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$
is well defined the function
$$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\,dt$$
Notice that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}F(x)=\sqrt\pi$$
The primitive of the Gaussian function has a lot of uses, mainly in statistic, as one defines the error function as the following
$$\text{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\,dt$$

Comment: Ok, I understand, how can this be extend to an arbitrary function (not necessary even) that is continuous in the whole line? Could you provide a more general approach?

Comment: If you want $$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ to be well defined, then $f$ i would say that must have finite integral over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I was wondering if one can avoid putting $-\infty$ in the lower limit. Like $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$$ with $a<x$. But this seems problematic to include.

Comment: If you define the integral function in that way, it is sufficient that $f$ is continuous. In fact $$F(x) = \int_a^x sin(t)dt$$ is well defined, while $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x sin(t)dt$$ is not.

Comment: But my $a$ is a paremeter $a(x)$.

Comment: Well, if $a=a(x)$ then i don't really know what are the conditions under which
$$F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$
is well defined, since it is an entirely new function.
Taking another step, and making it even more complicate, you can considere $b=b(x)$, and define
$$F(x)=\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)\,dt$$
and i don't really know what's gonna happen at this point.

Comment: I made a new post asking for the general case and received an answer in the comments. Maybe you want to take a look.